# TYPO3 StoragePid and Current

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

i build a simple commentary extbase extension, which i want to include with typoscript in a project extension (also extbase). The fluid code in the project extension looks like this:

```
<f:for each="{project.reports}" as="report">
    ...Content...
    {report -> f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.comments')}
</f:for>
```

"Reports" is an array of id's. The lib.comments typoscript looks like this:

```
lib.comments = USER
lib.comments  {
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Comments
    pluginName = Comments
    persistence.storagePid = ?
}
```

The StoragePid should match with the report id, so i tried:
    persistence.storagePid.cObject = TEXT
    persistence.storagePid.cObject.current = 1

But it doens't work. Has anyone an idea, which is the right way to set "current" to the storagePid?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable storage PID checking in your repository by placing method at its beginning:

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $this->defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
}
```

Then use `id` of current page by passing it to the repositories finder as common param and including as common constraint.

of course current page's UID you fetches as usual with:

```
$currentUid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, i do not know if I have understood you correctly. I include the Comments 3-5 times (In the for-array). I don't want to set the storagePid to the current page, further to the id, that i set in "report".
lib.comments = TEXT
lib.comments.current=1
works fine. But why not as an cObject?

Comment: So, what the `current` in your config means ? Sorry I don;t get it :/

Comment: I mean the stdWrap property current. When i set the following code in fluid: {report -> f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.comments')} - is "report" current. So if i set this in typoscript:
lib.comments = TEXT 
lib.comments.current=1

Fluid will render the field report.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and tried .current and .field to get the value from the cObject fluid view helper. As described, it works fine when creating a cObject TEXT but it seems to be impossible if it is USER or USER_INT. Does anyone know how to get the values from fluid template to TypoScript user functions?

Answer (score 0):

`persistence.storagePid.field = uid`

All fields of "report" which gets passed along with "report -> f:cObject" will be available to stdWrap property ".field".

You could also do

```
persistence.storagePid.debugData = 1
```

to list all available fields of $cObj->data