# The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper

Tags: templates, plugins, typo3

Im trying to make a typo3 extension and i want to show all relations(in this case cities) from region. I connected them  in them in the kickstarter like this:
[image: Domain Modeler]
i tried to print the cities in the regions single view doing this:

```
<table class="tx-collection-plan" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <f:translate key="tx_collectionplan_domain_model_region.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
        {region.name}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <f:translate key="tx_collectionplan_domain_model_region.cities" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <f:for each="{region.cities)" as="city">
                    <li>{city.name}</li>
                </f:for>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But i keep getting this error:
<kbd>**Oops, an error occurred!**



The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type
 "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ForViewHelper"</kbd>

***is there another solution to show all subparts of a region (with links that can be klicked -> like the list view of cities itself)?***

> EDIT: when i remove the for loop and just print city.name, i only get
>   the dot from li .... but nothing else

Comment: Please check the storage PID settings in your extension. You can see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074525/typo3-storagepid-and-current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution:**
all i need is

```
<table class="tx-collection-plan" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <f:translate key="tx_collectionplan_domain_model_region.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
        {region.name}
        </td>
        <td>
        <f:for each="{region.cities}" as="city">
        {city.name}
        </f:for>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the `<f:translate>` was unnecessary