# TYPO3: Automatic Record Storage Page for extension

Tags: plugins, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want the plugin to automatically select the page which it is used on as Record Storage Page and always thought this would happen by default, but apparently not on my TYPO3 (7.6.8) installation.

The plugin which was created by the Extension Builder only shows elements in the list view when I select a Record Storage Page. Leaving the Record Storage Page field empty results in an empty wrap at the frontend.

Is there a quick TS to solve this? Like:

```
plugin.tx_ext.recordStoragePage = this
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 StoragePid and Current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074525/typo3-storagepid-and-current)

Comment: In the answer linked by @rob-ot you'll find the solution

Comment: @rob-ot This wasn't 100%ly the answer I was looking for, but it gave me an idea what to google and I quickly solved the problem by myself. So thanks! EDIT: Oh, further below there _was_ actually the answer. Well... Still thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the code is as simple as I hoped it would be:

```
plugin.tx_ext.persistence.storagePid.field = uid
```